# Don't make the SAME http request to a service using RestTemplate and instead cache the response somewhere without using a DB?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, resttemplate

**Problem**

- I don't want to make the same HTTP request from my Spring Boot application using `RestTemplate` to a backend service because the response will be the same.
- The only solution I can think of is using a DB to store previous requests and responses. If the request is found in the DB then use that response from the DB instead of making the same HTTP request.
- Is there a better way to do this using Spring? I was thinking that Spring Caching could do this but after research that feature does not seem to be there.

Comment: Just use spring caching. Put the call with the `RestTemplate` in a component (or service) add `@Cacheable` and if called with the same parameters it will serve the result from the cache.

Comment: That's what I assumed when I heard the requirement. I did some googling and didn't find a solution yet. So it is possible with Spring Caching? Can someone provide a link or code snippet please? Also, thanks @M.Deinum for the edits!

Comment: What you need to do is already in my comment. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using spring cache. You can put RestTemplate in controller or service.
Refer - https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/